# How should I get progress messages for "npm update"?

Tags: git, npm

I have forked zippyui/react-datagrid. I am installing react-datagrid from my git repo as follows:

```
npm install --save git+https://github.com/vijayst/react-datagrid.git
```

After making updates to the git repo, I tried to do a npm update:

```
npm update react-datagrid
```

This seems to hang. Any idea how to get some sort of progress messages to ensure npm update is working?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loglevel can be added to any npm command as follows:

```
npm update react-datagrid --loglevel verbose
```

This gave an idea where most time was taken. It turned out that react-datagrid has lot of branches, one of which had a blob. By removing the redundant branches and pruning the repo, I was able to reduce the size of the repo from 61 MB to 6 MB.